# converting date format from numeric to text php

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, date

I have date field which generates

```
<?php $date = 11/12/2011;
$evdate = explode("/", $date);

$exday = $evdate[0];
$exmonth = $evdate[1];
$exyear = $evdate[2]; ?>
```

I need to output the below from `$exmonth.`

"This month is december"

How should i format a numerical value to text( i.e feb,jan ) ?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 'This month is ' . date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $exday, $exmonth, $exyear));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

- `M` : A short textual representation of a month, three letters   (Jan
  through Dec)
- `F` : A full textual representation of a month, such as
  January or March January through December

Comment: `date` expects a timestamp, passing just the month value [won't work](http://codepad.org/LPTy1PDH).

Comment: jan is getting printed, but the excact i specify is not getting printed

Comment: @AlienWebguy, sorry that downvote was me being hyperactive on coffee the other day and clicking on the wrong arrow. "Derp" for me too. Changed to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

For full month name: (December)

```
echo 'The month is ' . date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $exmonth, $exday, $exyear));
```

For three letter month name: (Dec)

```
echo 'The month is ' . date( 'M', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $exmonth, $exday, $exyear));
```

Comment: very valid, but i need it in text,this certainly worked           <?php echo 'The month is ' . date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $exmonth, $exday, $exyear));?>

Comment: Need what in text? As in, saved to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [mktime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

```
echo strftime("This month is %B", mktime(0, 0, 0, $exmonth, $exday, $exyear));
```

The `mktime` call converts your numbers into a php date object, and the `strftime` stands for "string formatted time" and will format your time according to the pattern given. Here, `%B` is the code used to give the month name. You can see in the docs all the codes you can use for other date components.